# How to plot Musical Notes on Sheet Music image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I wrote code to identify musical notes ('A4' for example) and their corresponding times within a .wav file. I then save this information in a .txt file.

I need to write a basic MATLAB plotting program that will take the information from the .txt file and plot the note at its corresponding frequency (vs. time) on an image of a music score. My overall goal, is to use GUIDE to transcribe an image of sheet music using the information from a .wav file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that implementing general functionality in MATLAB to plot sheet music is going to take you a very long time indeed. Instead, I would suggest either:

1. Find a java library that can do it such as jmusic, and call that from MATLAB, or
2. Get MATLAB to output some sort of text format from your notes such as MusicXML, and then call an external program to render it as sheet music.